# MarketPress vs. other WP ecommerce solutions

Tags: e-commerce, plugin-wp-e-commerce, plugins

**What experiences have you had with [MarketPress](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/e-commerce/) vs. other WP ecommerce solutions?** I found a client that wants to use it and I never worked with it before.

How does it compare with WooCommerce or WP e-Commerce? Or does anyone know of a good and recent comparison of WordPress ecommerce solutions? ...everything I find on this is either shallow or old...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions like this is are not really suitable for WPSE because they attract a lot of subjective, open ended opinion, for which there is often no right answer.

Let me give you a real world example.

I have used several WordPress E-commerce plugins, both free and premium types, I've also created my own custom solutions in certain cases too.

However I often recommend **JigoShop** which is free and from my experience I have found it to be a very robust commerce platform for WordPress, that appears well coded and in the instances where I have used it for client projects I've extended or modified its functionality where needed.

If you are also a developer which I'm getting a hint of (?) seeing as this is for a client, then if you know your way around the [**WordPress API**](http://codex.wordpress.com), you too would be able to use something like **JigoShop** to its full extent and power and in a situation where you need something a little off-beat, dive right in and extend its functionality.

The same could also be said for a host of other commerce type plugins.

Now back to the issue with questions like this, I've completely ignored mentioning Market Press and in place of something entirely different and while that's what you want to know in part, my opinion is subjective based upon my experience and skill level so much so that what I say could sway you one way or another to make a decision that's not right for you, or possibly entirely right.

When you couple that with several people all recommending different commerce platforms, you're going to be in a position of more confusion than certainty which is why questions like this should remain simply Google searches, to see what others are saying about **_*Market Press*_** vs **_*The Rest*_**.

- You want to look for people who have reviewed Market Press, legitimately, ideally not people who are affiliates of products too as their reviews are mostly biased.
- You should also compare the list of features the product has versus other similar products in the market to see if they meet your needs.

There are popular known contenders (and many more) in this space such as,

- **Cart66**
- **WooCommerce**
- **GetShopped**
- **Shopp**
- **Tribulant WordPress Shopping Cart**
- *and more...*

At one point I had wanted to test **Tribulant WordPress Shopping Cart**, but opted for **JigoShop** and have never had the need to go back to try Tribulant's solution. I have also used **Cart66** and found that to be a good solution too, but again, it comes down to features required, both now and in the future, which is why any opinion you receive here can do you more harm than good.

If you choose a particular plugin over another, then wish to extend the plugin with a unique feature or possible work out how to achieve a particular way of accessing/presenting data then this is where WPSE becomes your place of choice because questions relating to code that have tangible answers, ***right answers*** in respect to their functionality are the types of questions we like and the types of questions you'll receive the most helpful answers for.

---

PS. Just a quick side note, you'll notice when you go to reply as a **comment** to an answer you are limited by the amount of characters you can write in response. This is intentional and its not really an issue of increased database size either. Its designed for the most part (even if indirectly) NOT to promote back and forth discussion but rather **Question->Answer->Clarification** (in the form of Comment).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, but i was hoping to attract a lot of subjective answers - hoping some of them will also be well informed and thus get upvoted!

(Sidenote: Isn't such a site intended to be used as a "hive mind" that throws lots of answers back at you but properly sorted by the collective intelligence of others? I don't even like the fact that you can only mark one answer as "right".)

Comment: Questions like this mostly get closed because they don't meet the requirements outlined in the [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq). Its understandable, as WPSE is more about the technical help/code challenges of WP than open ended debate. Tthe "e-commerce" topic has been thrashed. However, like you,  also like open debates/discussion but if it were allowed,  the **real technical help** would get drowned out and there is nothing else like WPSE for free on such a level. Feel free to stop by our chat room because that's the place for open discussion with some very experienced devs!

Comment: Any answers to this question won't do you much justice because most people who answer these types of open ended questions (especially e-commerce plugin questions) rarely if ever provide sufficient evidence or support in what they're saying. Take a look and see for yourself. Its thin advice. Even my answer, while it provides opinion, doesn't give you a side by side run-down which is time consuming to write. Not everyone has that ***will***. There is nothing greater a benefit than you'll receive by comparing features against client requirements, then coming to chat about them in our chat room.

Comment: Ok, I understand you points. And thanks for suggesting me the chat room as a better place for such discussions! I'll let the question open for a few more hours just to see what/who "lands on it" and then I'll pick yours as the right answer and close it. Thanks for taking the time to explain instead of just closing it!

Comment: Off-topic, but need to say: kudos for such nice write-up, @userabuser! Excellent candidate for a meta-Q&A, or simply an A if a Q already exists there :)

Comment: @brasofilo Thanks. There's more I'd like to say, in that if it happens to make its way to meta/Q&A, I'll then add, which gives this post more context in addition to that already provided. That aside, I'm one for there being an area for such 'loosely' open questions to exist, yet which provide factual, tangible and useful answers which may quell such constant repetition of such questions, perhaps a consolidation of sorts. On the otherhand if its something the WPSE community does not want then there in itself lay the *idea* for someone to create a totally *separate* site just for that purpose!

Comment: This is the only one I can find: http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/967/are-theme-and-plugin-recommendation-guessing-games